# Plot single-coloured plane using sym.ezsurf in matlab

Tags: matlab, colors, plot

I would like to plot a single-coloured plane in a 3D-plot in matlab. The plane is created using ezsurf (sym.ezsurf), so it can't return a handle. It seems a dead simple task but still I can't find out how to avoid the plane changing its color depending on its "position".

So in the end, with this plane ...

```
syms x y z
zplane = (10*y)/31 - (9*x)/31 + 112/31;
```

... something like this should be done (this won't work as sym.ezsurf won't return the handle h):

```
hSurface = ezsurf(zplane, [2, 8, 2, 8]);
set(hSurface,'FaceColor',[1 0 0],'FaceAlpha',0.5);
```

Thank you very much,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An anonymous user tried to provide an answer by editing the question:

> (I am note registred to answer but i found a solution to "fool"
>   matlab.)
>
> You can change your colormap to a single color using "colormap([0 0 1])"
>   and thus get a single colored ezsurf.]